# Law of Cosine: Trigonometry Word Problem

Tags: trigonometry

The longest side of a triangular lot is 21 meters. If another side of this lot is 17 meters and if the angle formed by thus side and third side is 95 degrees, how long is the third side?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Clearly you know this problem involves the law of cosines; have you tried using it?

Comment: Hello, I have tried but I think it has no answer. Do you have an answer for it?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried as part of the question statement, so we can give you answers that address your point of confusion, or what you did wrong.

Comment: the answer I got is 28

Comment: $28$ is close to correct if the $95^{\circ}$ angle is between the $17$ and $21$ sides, but that's not what you said in your problem statement. Draw a careful picture as the first answer below suggests.

Comment: If you do not mind, can you tell me the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Draw a picture.  A 95 degree angle is a little more than right, and the longest side will be opposite it.  Label what you know.  Write down the law of cosines and identify the sides with the variables.  Solve.  What step is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

law of cosine gives you
roots($[1 -2*17*\cos(95) -(21^2-17^2)]$)
$=10.9359$

Comment: why the downvote?